# When your BroadcastReceiver is invoked via an Intent, what process does it run on?

Tags: android, process, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I know that we have 10 seconds to handle an intent; otherwise, watch dog timer will kick in.  And its suppose be a light-weight function.  So my question is, does the BroadcastReceiver run in the same process as your root activity?  Or does it run on Zygote system process?

Comment: As far as I know, not only same process, but same thread also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So my question is, does the BroadcastReceiver run in the same process as your root activity?

Yes. And, as xandy notes, it also runs on the main application thread. Your `BroadcastReceiver` should either do its work very quickly or call `startService()` on an `IntentService` (or something) that can do long-running work on a background thread.

BTW, I am pleased to see that you have time to spend on Android application development, now that you are no longer busy saving the world. It must be nice to spend time on a hobby and not worry about being shot at, blown up, etc. :-)

Comment: Thanks!  That helps a lot.  Yes, I had a lot of time after the series and then jumped right into the movie.  I have some problems with memory loss, but I am getting the hang of it :D